# What is the difference between the sources "google" and "google-play" in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: firebase, google-play, firebase-analytics

I see the following install sources for my app in Firebase Analytics:

[image: Console screen]

What are the sources "google" and "google-play"? What is the difference?

"google-play" generates more revenue, but what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ***google*** source is attributed for the Adwords campaign that draws user to install your app. This can be search, UAC, Display or Video.

The ***google-play*** campaign is attributed when the user gets to your app via [Google Play Campaign Attribution](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-campaigns).

Comment: So each install from Google Play should be attributed with 'google-play', isn't it? What is the `(direct)` source then?

Comment: "Direct" is attributed when Analytical tool was not able to backtrack the source of the attribution it came from. More details available online.

Comment: I have a 10 to 1 ratio on (direct) vs everything else too. Are these mostly pirated downloads?

Answer (score 0):

> Google

means that the user found your App in the Google websearch and installed it directly.

> Google Play

means that the user found it in the Google Play store. 
**EDIT:** I think only if its installed over the Google Play website, but I'm not completly sure. Are you using ad campains?

Comment: Why the 'google-play' amount is so low? If 'google-play' is Google Play serach, what is '(direct)' channel? Or is 'google-play' channel specific in something?

Comment: I'm using cross-promotion with house ads at AdMob.